# QGIS: Manually control "showFeatureCount" display for layer labels in legends

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, display, feature-count

Is there a way to manually control the feature count for vector layer legend entries in a print layout in QGIS?

1. Activate feature count for a vector layer in the layer tree context menu for the layer
2. Add a legend containing this layer in a print layout
3. Uncheck auto-update
4. Deactivate feature count for the layer in the layer tree
5. See the layer label in the print layout. The feature count is still there, but there's no option to manually control its display.

Am I missing something or is this really a feature that does not exist yet?

[image: Layer tree view]

[image: Print layout legend view]

Comment: If you set auto-update ON again - then the feature count should disappear.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I meant. I [found the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456608/qgis-manually-control-showfeaturecount-display-for-layer-labels-in-legends?noredirect=1#answer-456742) myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature count display within the legend in a QGIS print layout can be controlled via the button with the sum sign below the layer tree in the legend options (right button).
[image]

I expected the option within the legend layer context menu, that's why I did not find it.

Comment: Awesome. Don't suppose there's a way to do that automatically - Mine doesn't but it might be because I'm using a Theme?